# averaging images, code doesn't work

Tags: matlab

I have this matlab code for creating averages of several images:
cd('C:\images')

```
all_images=dir('*.jpg');
[sj,xx]=size(all_images);
j=1;
file_name=char(all_images(j).name);
tmp=imread(file_name);
[m,n]=size(tmp);
template=zeros(m,n);

for i=1:length(all_images)
    file_name=char(all_images(i).name);
    tmp=double(imread(file_name));
    template=template+tmp;
end

template=template/length(all_images);

imagesc(template)

imwrite(uint8(template),'template.jpg','jpg')
```

The case is that I obtained the following error:

Error

> using + Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error

> in averagetemplate (line 15) template=template+tmp;

Any idea? I have to say that I am newbie in matlab coding.

Thanks

Comment: Are you certain your files contain images of the same size? That's likely your problem.

Comment: Yes all the images have the same size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `[m,n]=size(tmp)` in line 6 to `[m,n,~]=size(tmp)`and your problem will be solved.

In the below code :

```
[m,n]=size(tmp)
```

Matlab is computing `n*3` as the column of matrix so you will get the *dimension* error in next few line.

Comment: It worked fine in my system. Did you get the same error ?

Comment: Exactly, the same.  Which version of matlab are you using?

Comment: @unomas83 - Matlab2017a. It doesn't matter my friend.

Comment: @unomas83 _ Put a break point on line 6 and run your code then click step in editor menu. When you reach line 7, in command window get the size of `tmp` to check whether it computes wrong or not.

Comment: @unomas83- `template = zeros(m,n,3)` also do this.

Comment: I put the breakpoint. The size of tmp is 800 600 3, so it seems there is no problem computing this. I also modify the code with `template = zeros(m,n,3)`, but still get the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159796/discussion-between-pouyan-bn-and-unomas83).

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your temp variable with what appears to be a single value here:

tmp=double(imread(file_name));

and it may be different dimensions M x N regardless. Matlab is saying to add matricies they have to have same number of rows and cols.